# right and left padding in a flexbox container is stretching the child image

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox, direction column, with four children, an image and three text elements.
The image has correct proportions when there's no padding in the container, but the more right and left padding I add in the container, the more vertically stretched the image gets. This is only happening on mobile devices, iPhone, iPad, etc.
It's as if the flexbox is treating the image as a text element, with more padding it stretches it to fit more content.

align-self: center; and align-items: center; are not working in this case

Here's a simplified code.

```
<li class="painting" > 
   <img src="src">
   <h5 class="Title">{{title}}</h5>
   <p class="Summary">{{summary}}</p>
   <p class="Price">Price: {{price}}</p>
</li>
```

the CSS

```
li{
    width: 22%;
    margin: 3vh 2%;
    padding: 1% 2%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto 0;
    align-self: center;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
h5{
    margin: 1rem 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
}
p{
    margin: 1rem 0 0 0;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    flex-shrink: 1; 
}
```

Wrapping the image in a non-flex container solves the problem, but I would like to understand the problem.
I don't get this behaviour and why exactly it happens on mobile devices. Could anyone shed some light on the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [object-fit](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp) property to avoid stretching the image.

Note: Avoid assigning percentage values for padding, margin etc. You can always make use of `media-query` for responsive padding.

Comment: Thanks this works, the image height gets corrected, but it leaves white space above and below the image. As if the image is shrunk to the correct height inside a stretched container. I don't know if you get what I mean.

Comment: wrapping the image in a non-flex container works better, but I don't understand why this happens on mobile devices

Answer (score 0):

To prevent your child image being stretched set a width on the image tag then constrain the width in css.

HTML:

```html
<img src="src" width="400">
```

Then change your CSS:

```css
img {
max-width: 100%;
}
```